# How to check if someones input is Present (Than show link)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, devise

I run Devise on Rails and added 2 new inputs in the Edit Registration Form (Facebook and Twitter Links). Now in the User's Page i need to show the links, BUT if someone didn't entered  his social Links, the buttons still appear. The Code for the links is beneath.

```
<%= link_to "Facebook", @user.facebooklink, :target => '_blank' %>          
<%= link_to "Twitter", @user.twitterlink, :target => '_blank' %>
```

How can i check if a user did enter theire Social Links and ONLY THEN show them the links in the Profile Page?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it with:

```
<% if @user.facebooklink.present? %>
  <%= link_to 'Facebook', @user.facebooklink, target: '_blank' %>
<% end %>
```

and the same for Twitter.

Comment: Thank You :) somehow i did write it in a wrong way.. (newbie here) thx